# How to get the Files by only File Name from Sharepoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Currently I am getting the list of documents as following:

```
 private ClientContext _clientContext;
 var oList = _clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SERVERURL);
 var oQuery = new CamlQuery();
 var fileList = oList.GetItems(oQuery);
_clientContext.Load(fileList);
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

It gives me all the files that is on the server.

But what if I know the files that I want to open from SharePoint and Read? I don't want to load all the files and then loop through them  , instead want to get that particular file from SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

You may use your `CamlQuery`:

```
oQuery.Query = 
@"<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>DocTitle</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>";
```

For more details read [Query Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521.aspx).